# Get Selection from Lookup Table CSOM PowerShell in Project Server

Tags: powershell, csom, project-server

I have a custom field at the project level that is a lookup table (single select).  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the value of the selection from the lookup table.  I can get the lookup table:

```
$lookupTables = $projContext.LookupTables
$projContext.Load($lookupTables)
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()

$myLookupTable = $lookupTables.GetByGuid('GUID FOR LOOKUP TABLE')
$projContext.Load($myLookupTable)
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

and I can get the field:
    $custFields = $project.CustomFields
    $projContext.Load($custFields)
    $projContext.ExecuteQuery()

```
$myField = $custFields.GetByGuid([Guid]"{GUID FOR FIELD}") 
$projContext.Load($myField )
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

When I look at values in myField everything looks ok.  I can see the .LookupDefaultValue but  when I try to get the selection of the Field, I'm not quite sure what to do.  I've Tried:

```
$myfieldvalue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue($myField).LookupValue
```

But it comes out as  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue

I've tried

```
$myfieldvalue = $myField .Value
$projContext.Load($myfieldvalue )
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

but that blows up on the Load.

Answer (score 0):

Mark,

Take a look at this example on how to update lookup table values. I think it could help you move in the right direction.

[Update Project Server 2010 / 2013 Lookup table with values from a text file](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-Server-Lookup-table-bb1ae14f)

Here's an example in C# that may help also.

[How To Read The Values Of Fields Bound To Lookup Tables Via The Client Object Model](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/how-to-read-the-values-of-fields-bound-to-lookup-tables-via-the-client-object-model/)

Take a look at this example using REST to query Project Server.

[Using PowerShell And REST With Project Server (Or SharePoint) For Reporting](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/using-powershell-and-rest-with-project-server-or-sharepoint-for-reporting/)

Comment: I looked at that, but that article focuses on the lookup tables, and not the field that uses the lookup tables.  I can find lots of examples of writing, but none of reading the values from the fields that use lookup tables.  Seems like the reading should be the easy part.

Comment: Mark, you may want to contact the author of the solution above. I'm sure he'll have some ideas for you.

Comment: I have done that.  Hopefully he will answer.  I am shocked at how difficult this is and that no one knows how to do this.

Comment: I don't have project server, so I have no way to test any of my suggestions. Sorry.